# Module naming in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, js-amd

We can use AMD compatible versions of BackboneJS and UnderscoreJS

I had a look in the AMD compatible library for both (https://github.com/amdjs/) and below is the relevant code to make them AMD compatible.

BackboneJS (AMD);

```
else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
// AMD
define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
// Export global even in AMD case in case this script is loaded with
// others that may still expect a global Backbone.
root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
});
```

UnderscoreJS (AMD);

```
 // AMD define happens at the end for compatibility with AMD loaders
// that don't enforce next-turn semantics on modules.
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
define('underscore', function() {
return _;
});
}
```

Now to use these AMD compatible libraries in our code, we say;

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        "jquery": "libs/jquery-1.8.3",
        "underscore": "libs/underscore-amd",
        "backbone": "libs/backbone-amd"
    }
});
```

Now I read that the name for the backbone module can be anything, but the name for underscore must be “underscore” and for underscore, the capitalization is important.

Why is the difference based on how the library is defined?

Answer (score 2):

The `define` function can be called with or without a name for the module being defined. This call does not have the module name. It starts with an array of dependencies:

```
define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
```

RequireJS will assign a module name on the basis of the base name of the file in which the `define` appears or on the basis of the name you give in the `paths` configuration. You could put `paths: { platypus: '... path to file' }` and your module would be named `platypus`.

This call has a module name:

```
define('underscore', function() {
```

It names the module as `underscore`. (The first argument is not an array, so RequireJS interprets it as a module name.) And when the name is set with `define`, it does not change, ever. So when you put it as a dependency it has to be called `underscore`. (You could use `map` in your RequireJS config to remap the name but ultimately the module name is fixed to `underscore`.) If you tried the `platypus` example above with this module, RequireJS would generate an error because it would find a module named `underscore` but none named `platypus`.

Specifying module names in `define` calls without an **explicit** and **substantial** reason to do so is **bad practice**. The documentation for RequireJS [recommends](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename) not doing it:

> These [i.e. module names] are normally generated by the optimization tool. You can explicitly name modules yourself, but it makes the modules less portable -- if you move the file to another directory you will need to change the name. It is normally best to avoid coding in a name for the module and just let the optimization tool burn in the module names. The optimization tool needs to add the names so that more than one module can be bundled in a file, to allow for faster loading in the browser.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the order/sequence is like this...if the module name is not defined inside the module via define() (say backbone)...then it is named as per that defined in paths (while doing requirejs.config())